# Match first substring option out of several options in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the string

- `string = 'fail alm alarm'` and
- a set of substrings `substrings=[norm,alm,fail]` that I want to match.

However I want `norm` and `alm` to have a higher matching priority than `fail`.

I wrote the `pattern=r'norm|alm|fail'`

thinking that since `norm` and `alm` appear before `fail` they would be given priority but
`re.search('norm|alm|fail', 'fail alm alarm')` returns

`<re.Match object; span=(20, 24), match='fail'>`

But I would like it to return `alm`.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: is splitting the string by spaces and checking via a loop an option ?

Comment: sadly it is not. However both your answer as well as trincot's solved my problem! 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in the regex only influences the order in which the regex engine tries to find a match at the *current* position.

To achieve what you want, you'll need to look ahead and check there is no "norm" or "alm" when going for "fail". The pattern for that would be:

```
norm|alm|fail(?!.*(?:norm|alm))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` and then check for the presence of the strings one by one:

```py
import re

string = 'fail alm alarm'
substrings_ordered_by_importance = ["norm", "alm", "fail"]
pattern = "|".join(substrings_ordered_by_importance)

matches = re.findall(pattern, string) # >>> ['fail', 'alm']
result = None
for substring in substrings_ordered_by_importance:
    if substring in matches:
        result = substring
        break

result # >>> "alm"
```